# "Equivalent resistance" of diode as \$V/I\$ used to evaluate an approximation

Tags: resistors, diodes, resistance, voltmeter, internal-resistance

Consider the circuit in picture, used to measure the voltage across diode and current flowing through it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvFJ8T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this circuit I do measure the exact voltage across diode (\$V\$) with voltmeter, nevertheless the current measured with ammeter (\$I\$) is **not** the current passing through the diode, since \$I=I_d+I_v\$.

To evaluate the error committed doing the approximation \$I=I_d\$, is it correct to see if $$V/I << R_v$$
?

Infact, supposing in first place that the approximation \$I=I_d\$ is correct, and also interpreting the ratio \$V/I_d=V/I\$  as the "equivalent resistance" of diode, then, using the current divider, if \$R_d <<R_v\$, then the approximation  is justified *a posteriori*.

In other words is it correct to interpret \$V/I_d\$ as the resistance of diode, and consider the diode equivalent to a resistor for this porpouse (i.e. to evaluate this approximation)?

Comment: you mean the diode killer circuit you have drawn

Comment: first sign of old age    ;-)

Comment: Your voltmeter (which is really an ammeter) will have a characteristic ohms/volt figure so if you wanted you could model this resistance in **but** unless you're looking at nA - uA range of diode current a modern digital voltmeter will have very little loading effect.

Answer (score 1):

The bulk resistance of the diode is not V/Id but rather ΔV/ΔI  The lowest value is reached at max rated current and is approx Rd=1/Pd [ Ω ] for Pd rating on package.

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard diode equation
$$Idiode = Is * e^[qv/ktn]$$ and letting n be 1, the diode current will increase by 2.718X for every 0.026 volts increase in Vdiode.

For this idealized equation [n usually is not exactly 1], we know exactly the diode's linearized resistance: at 1mA, Rdiode is 26 ohms; at 0.1mA, Rdiode is 260 ohms; Rdiode is 0.026/Idiode(amps).

This equation also applied to the transconductance (the 'gm') of bipolar transistors and diffpairs; this exact predictability makes discrete design a very fun project.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is, so long as Rv is sufficiently large vs the diodes equivalent resistance. This assumption may have difficulty to hold when thee current is very small, like ua or less.

I would put a resistor in serial with the diode as a precaution.

Edit, to give you a sense of how high the equivalent resistance can vary as the voltage across the diode changes.

For a typical small signal silicon diode like 1n4148, the equivalent resistance at 0v is about 25Meg. 400k at 300nv, 2k at 600mv and less than 1k at 700mv.

edit 2: ltspice showed an equivalent resistance of 18Meg @ 0v.